# Is it mandatory to update all back links with my new link

Tags: seo, google-search

I changed my domain to a new domain and anew custom permalinks.
I performed the redirect and every URL is redirected properly to the new domain URL!

Now I have many backlinks from the old domain that are under my controls and others that other users share it over the internet.

**My question is** should I update all backlinks that I can control with the new URL structure or doesn't matter because the old URL already redirects properly to the right URL! so if someone clicks on the old backlink it will redirects properly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's definitely worth it to update all the backlinks that you control. I wouldn't worry too much about trying to get links updated that are out of your control, though.

While redirects will handle users who still end up on the old URLs, they add another DNS+HTTP round-trip, making the link load slightly slower.

But a bigger reason is to signal trust to the search engines. If the search engines see a bunch of URLs that were pointing to the old domain all switch over to the new domain, they will perform the migration more quickly and confidently.

Also, if anyone right-clicks one of your links and selects "copy link", you'll want them to have the new link instead of the old one, which is again about search engine signals and load speed.

Finally, if you ever decide not to renew the old domain in the far future, you'll want to make sure as many links as possible on the internet are pointing to the new domain.

Comment: Additionally if you have links from your own domain to the old page, Google could get confused about which you prefer and sometimes use the old links as canonicals.